# emulator android sdk don't work

Tags: android, sdk, compiler-errors, android-emulator, emulation

please help me to fix this error,  i start android sdk emulator and im get this message :

my emulator and the message errors

emulator : message errors.

```
[2014-11-08 11:24:58 - BeetleGame] Android Launch!
[2014-11-08 11:24:58 - BeetleGame] adb is running normally.
[2014-11-08 11:24:58 - BeetleGame] Performing com.game.BeetleshotMainActivity activity launch
[2014-11-08 11:24:59 - BeetleGame] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'android'
[2014-11-08 11:24:59 - BeetleGame] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'android'
[2014-11-08 11:26:02 - Emulator] emulator: device fd:572
[2014-11-08 11:26:02 - Emulator] 
[2014-11-08 11:26:02 - Emulator] HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
[2014-11-08 11:26:10 - Emulator] creating window 0 0 428 760
[2014-11-08 11:26:11 - BeetleGame] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-11-08 11:26:11 - BeetleGame] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:531 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:531 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glShaderSource:1701 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glCompileShader:351 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderiv:1224 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetShaderInfoLog:1247 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDeleteShader:505 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:154 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:154 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glBindAttribLocation:178 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glBindAttribLocation:178 error 0x501
[2014-11-08 11:26:47 - Emulator] ../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glLinkProgram:1571 error 0x501
```

Comment: Edit your AVD again with proper minimum and maximum target then run it..

Comment: My AVD: Updated AVD 'android' based on Android 5.0, Intel Atom (x86) processor,
with the following hardware config:
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=none
hw.camera.front=none
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Galaxy Nexus
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=320
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=768
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
skin.dynamic=no
vm.heapSize=64